# Higher residuosity problem, but with a known factorization

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Given

- two large primes $p$ and $q$,
- two arbitrary odd integers $a$ and $b$,
- $x \in Z_{n^2}^*$ where $n$ = $pq$,

find whether there exists numbers $c$ and $d$ that are distinct elements in $Z_{n^2} \setminus \{0,1\}$ such that
$x = c^a.d^b \mod n^2$

I assume the problem is called [higher residuosity problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher_residuosity_problem) if we ignore $b$ and $d$ and is easy to solve given the factorization?

Comment: Without at least a motivation for crypto use, I can't see why this isn't off topic.

Comment: I know questions must be beneficial to all and this one helps only me. But this is just a YES/NO question as to whether someone has come across a problem like this and if yes, probably a link would help. That's all. Thanks :)

Comment: Most cases you can solve by setting $d=1$. Do you have any further conditions on $x, a, b$ and $n$?